# split string using ng-list inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to split data inside ng-repeat using ng-list which is not working

```
tr(ng-repeat='row in displayedCollection', style='padding:5px')
   td {{row.ID}}
   td 
     span(data-ng-hide="editMode") {{row.SOME[0]}}
     select.form-control.trkatn(name="SOME", data-ng-model="row.SOME", data-ng-show="editMode", ng-list="&#58;", ng-trim="false")
```

here data in `displayedCollection` is coming from database using ajax and the values are somewhat like below example

```
[{ ID: '023YHZ', SOME: 'Value12 1448883027057'},
 {ID: '023NHZ', SOME: 'Value32 1448883027057'},
 {ID: '023YJZ', SOME: 'Value23 1448883027057'}]
```

now I want to extract value12 from `some` and other.

i tried doing it however it is showing 1st character of `SOME` if I use `row.SOME[0]` and full `SOME` value if I use `row.SOME` i.e `Value12 1448883027057` for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to split the string first

```
row.SOME.split(' ') 
>['Value12','1448883027057']
row.SOME.split(' ')[0]
>'Value12'
row.SOME.split(' ')[1]
>'1448883027057'
```

Comment: oh great that worked, however can you please tell me how it is working inside {{}}

Comment: The docs on [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) should clear things up. Essentially you can do most javascript things in angular expressions, such as call `String.split`.